# Microsoft Graph API: creating a plan returns 'MaximumPlannerPlans' exception

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create multiple plans for my Team/Group using Microsoft Graph API. When I call graph api for the first time for any specific group, it's working fine .

But once first plan gets created, for the rest of all the requests it is throwing this error:

> "MaximumPlannerPlans :The request exceeded allowed limits"

Can anybody tell me how many plans for a Team/ Group can be created using Microsoft Graph API ?

Comment: getting the same error, created an issue around the documentation so at some point Microsoft documents it https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3235

Answer (score 1):

Currently the number of plans that can be created in a Group through either the API or Planner UI is one. However, multiple boards in Teams are allowed, and can be created using the UI in Teams app.

Comment: It looks like that now you can create multiple plans through Teams UI. However it looks like you can only create up to one plan per group through the graph API, that limit includes previously created plans through any mean (UI, API…)

Comment: we've just pushed a PR through to make this clearer in the documentation as well. If this is an important feature, please make the request in UserVoice. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis